# How can I retain Context while handling errors with onErrorResume()?

Tags: java, project-reactor

As is, this test passes:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;
import reactor.util.context.Context;

public class ReactorContextTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        String key = "some key";
        String value = "some value";
        Mono<Void> mono = Mono.just(value)
                .flatMap(v -> Mono.<Void>empty().contextWrite(Context.of(key, v)))
//                .onErrorResume(Exception.class, t -> {
//                    System.out.println("onErrorResume() triggered...");
//                    return Mono.empty();
//                })
                ;

        StepVerifier.create(mono)
                .expectAccessibleContext()
                .contains(key, value)
                .then()
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

but once you uncomment those few lines of code and run it once more, you notice two things:

1. The log *never* gets printed
2. The test fails

   ```
   java.lang.AssertionError: Expected value some value for key some key, key not present
   Context: Context0{}
   Captured at: onErrorResume
   ```

Here's the culprit:

```java
// Mono

    public final Mono<T> onErrorResume(Function<? super Throwable, ? extends Mono<? extends
            T>> fallback) {
        return onAssembly(new MonoOnErrorResume<>(this, fallback));
    }
```

In summary:

1. `onErrorResume()` returns a brand-new `Publisher`
2. That `Publisher`'s `Context` has no entries whatsoever and seemingly doesn't delegate context queries to the `Publisher` it wraps (I may have phrased it wrong, but I hope you get my point)
3. Thus it doesn't matter if `onErrorResume()` is even triggered – say goodbye to your sweet `Context` anyway

Not all `onErrorX()` methods are bad. A test with a chained `onErrorContinue()` passes (it *doesn't* return a new `Publisher`). `flatMap()` also somehow preserves the `Context` (it *does* return a new `Publisher`)

**How can I solve this problem?** I need to be able to switch to a different `Publisher` on error after `Context` writes *while* keeping `Context` accessible from my tests