# How do I assert on ReactiveSecurityContextHolder's contents?

Tags: java, testing, spring-security

***Note.** This question is related to [my earlier one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084826/how-can-i-retain-context-while-handling-errors-with-onerrorresume) but different. That question was about Project Reactor, this one is about Spring WebFlux Security*

Here's a simple authentication filter (or rather, *authentication extraction* filter, I don't authenticate the claims here, for simplicity)

```java
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.ServerAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class BasicWebFilter implements WebFilter {
    ServerAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter = new ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter();

    @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return authenticationConverter.convert(exchange)
                .flatMap(authentication -> chain.filter(exchange)
                        .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)));
    }
}
```

Suppose I want to test it. This works

```java
package com.example.dynamicgateway.misc;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class GenericTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        String username = "username", password = "password";
        MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.get("/")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "basic " + HttpHeaders.encodeBasicAuth(username, password, null))
                .build();
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.builder(request).build();

        WebFilterChain chainMock = mock(WebFilterChain.class);
        given(chainMock.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        BasicWebFilter basicWebFilter = new BasicWebFilter();
        StepVerifier.create(basicWebFilter.filter(exchange, chainMock))
                .expectAccessibleContext()
                .assertThat(c -> StepVerifier.create(c.<Mono<SecurityContext>>get(SecurityContext.class))
                        .expectNextMatches(sc -> {
                            Authentication authentication = sc.getAuthentication();
                            return authentication.getPrincipal().equals(username) &&
                                    authentication.getCredentials().equals(password);
                        })
                        .verifyComplete())
                .then()
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

However, there's a major issue with the test, it's very fragile. Here's how I can modify the filter's code to make the test fail

```java
                .flatMap(authentication -> chain.filter(exchange)
                        .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication)))
                .onErrorResume(Exception.class, t -> {
                    ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
                    return response.setComplete();
                });
```

The test fails because I assert on the most downstream operator which is no longer `MonoFlatMap` (which somehow retains original `Context`) but `MonoOnErrorResume` (which [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78084826/how-can-i-retain-context-while-handling-errors-with-onerrorresume))

What are more robust strategies to test the contents of `ReactiveSecurityContextHolder`? If it's possible, I'd prefer to keep Spring out and keep my tests truly unit (no Spring context initialization)

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of fruitless attempts and painful debugging, I came up with this working solution

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.ReactiveSecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebHandler;
import org.springframework.web.server.handler.DefaultWebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

public class AuthenticationFilterTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        String username = "username", password = "password";
        MockServerHttpRequest request = MockServerHttpRequest.get("/")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "basic " + HttpHeaders.encodeBasicAuth(username, password, null))
                .build();
        MockServerWebExchange exchange = MockServerWebExchange.builder(request).build();

        WebHandler handler = mock(WebHandler.class);
        given(handler.handle(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.empty());
        WebFilter authenticationAssertingFilter = (e, c) -> ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
                .filter(a -> a.getPrincipal().equals(username) && a.getCredentials().equals(password))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new AssertionError("No expected authentication")))
                .flatMap(a -> c.filter(e));

        WebFilterChain webFilterChain = new DefaultWebFilterChain(handler, List.of(
                new BasicWebFilter(), authenticationAssertingFilter));
        StepVerifier.create(webFilterChain.filter(exchange))
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

I still look forward for your input, if you have any